# Invalid date issue in safari with moment js

Tags: javascript, safari, momentjs

```
moment('2023-05-23').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

Above Moment js Date return Invalid date in safari browser only.It's working fine in chrome , firebox and other browsers

Any Solution for this issue ?

[image]

**Safari version** :- 14.1.2
**Moment version** :- 2.29.3

```js
const date = moment('2023-05-23').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
console.log(date)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.3/moment.min.js" ></script>
```

Comment: Which version of safari and moment do you use?

Comment: Check it in question description

Comment: [Moment is dead](https://momentjs.com/docs/) use [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl)